# How can I get the NumLock state in C++ in a platform independent way? I am primarily having problems with the Unix side

Tags: c++, c, linux, ioctl

I am trying to get the state of the NumLock key in a platform independent fashion in a C/C++ application. I can get the status using GetKeyState and #defines for the Windows code, but I am having problems with the Unix code (see below).

The code fails with an "Invalid Argument", err code 22 - but I do not understand why. I have tried various different ioctl requests (KDGETLED, KDGKBLED, KDGKBMETA) without success and have run out of ideas.

BTW the only reason for it being two functions was that I was struggling to open the "/dev/..." file and trying different files! This is now fixed (by adding the user to the "input" group - but ideally I would like to avoid this necessity).

```
#defined (_WIN32)
// Code here works ok
#else
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/kd.h>
    #include <sys/vt.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sstream>

    int fdKeybd;
    int tryStrForInput(std::string &inStr, int *pNumLed)
    {
        int testVal = -1;
        std::string kybdStr = inStr;

        printf("\nTry: %s", kybdStr.c_str());
        fdKeybd = open(kybdStr.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

        if ( fdKeybd < 0 ) {
            printf(" Opening file : Failed.  ");
            printf ("Error no is : %d  ", errno);
            printf("Error description is : %s",strerror(errno));

        } else {
            testVal = ioctl(fdKeybd, KDGKBMETA, pNumLed);
            if(testVal != -1) printf(" Success"); 
            else {
                printf(" Getting NumLock : Failed.  ");
                printf ("Error no is : %d  ", errno);
                printf("Error description is : %s",strerror(errno));
            }
        }
        return testVal;
    }

    bool isNumlockActivated(void)
    {
        int NUM_LED = 0x00;
        bool bNumLockOn = false;
        int testVal = -1;

        std::string kybdStr = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd";
        testVal = tryStrForInput(kybdStr, &NUM_LED);

        if(testVal != -1) {
            if((NUM_LED == 0x02) || (NUM_LED == 0x03) || (NUM_LED == 0x06) || (NUM_LED == 0x07)) {
                bNumLockOn = true;
            }
        }
        close(fdKeybd);
    
        return bNumLockOn;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: The existence of a keyboard is not platform-independent. (And your attempted method isn't Unix-variant-independent or keyboard-independent.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry - I am not a Unix expert by any means! Could you help clarify your points please. I understand that keyboards are not platform independent - but they are very common and hence it should be possible to find a reasonably common method to find out whether a keyboard state is present!. Also I am not sure why this code is not Unix-variant-independent (can it be - or is it not possible). I can change to /dev/input/event2 for the keyboard device string if that is better.

Comment: Is there a better way to get the numlock key from inside a c/c++ application. As I said I can do the Windows side, but with Unix (and its many variants) I am out of my depth - as it happens I do not need to worry about mobile platforms atm.

Answer (score 1):

After much stumbling about in the dark I found the following code works for the Linux side. The reason being I was trying to get the wrong file descriptor (all I actually needed was the standard input) and hence why it did not work.

This posted in case it helps anyone else.

```
bool isNumlockActivated(void)
    {
        int fdKeybd = STDIN_FILENO; // Normally 0
        int NUM_LED = 0x00;
        bool bNumLockOn = false;
        int testVal = ioctl(fdKeybd, KDGKBLED, &NUM_LED);
        if(testVal == -1) {
            printf(" Getting NumLock : Failed.  ");
            printf ("Error no is : %d  ", errno);
            printf("Error description is : %s",strerror(errno));
        } else {
            if((NUM_LED == 0x02) || (NUM_LED == 0x03) || (NUM_LED == 0x06) || (NUM_LED == 0x07)) {
                bNumLockOn = true;
            }
        }
        return bNumLockOn;
    }
```

However please note that this is only picking up on the numLock LED state. So if ioctl has been used to control the numLock LED you would have to find the correct key state instead - probably by using a different ioctl request (look at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/ioctl_list.htm)